# Detours Hook memcpy Not Working

Tags: c++, hook, memcpy, detours

I have programmed hook for `memcpy` but it only calls on the end of the program.

Not each time, when was function called. Also the adresses are different.

This is the hook:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include<iostream>
#include "detours\detours.h"

#pragma comment( lib, "msvcrt.lib" )
#pragma comment( lib, "detours.lib" )
//#pragma comment( lib, "detoured.lib" )

//int (WINAPI *Real_Send)(SOCKET s, const char *buf, int len, int flags) = send;
//int WINAPI Mine_Send(SOCKET s, const char* buf, int len, int flags);

//void *memcpy(void *dest,const void *src,size_t count);
void *(*Real_Memcpy)(void *dest, const void *src, size_t count) = memcpy;
void *(*Real_Memcpy_add)(void *dest, const void *src, size_t count) = &memcpy;
void * Mine_Memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t count);


void* Mine_Memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t count) {
    HANDLE hFile;
    BOOL bErrorFlag = FALSE;
    DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
    char cislo[24]; // just big enough

    sprintf(cislo,"0x%08x", Real_Memcpy_add);

    MessageBoxA(0, cislo, cislo, 0);
    MessageBoxA(0, (char *)src, (char *)src, 0);


    /*hFile = CreateFileA("C:\\Users\\edit\\Documents\\test.txt",                // name of the write
        FILE_APPEND_DATA,          // open for writing
        0,                      // do not share
        NULL,                   // default security
        OPEN_ALWAYS,             // create new file only
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,  // normal file
        NULL);
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        MessageBoxA(0, "Canot open file", "Error", 0);
    }
    bErrorFlag = WriteFile(
        hFile,           // open file handle
        src,      // start of data to write
        count,  // number of bytes to write
        &dwBytesWritten, // number of bytes that were written
        NULL);            // no overlapped structure
    if (FALSE == bErrorFlag)
    {
        MessageBoxA(0, "canot write to file", "Error", 0);
    }
    const char * str = "\r\n";
    bErrorFlag = WriteFile(
        hFile,           // open file handle
        str,      // start of data to write
        strlen(str) + 1,  // number of bytes to write
        &dwBytesWritten, // number of bytes that were written
        NULL);            // no overlapped structure
    if (FALSE == bErrorFlag)
    {
        MessageBoxA(0, "canot write to file", "Error", 0);
    }




    CloseHandle(hFile);

    return Real_Memcpy(dest, src, count);*/
    return 0x0;
}


BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID) {
    switch (dwReason) {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        DetourTransactionBegin();
        DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
        DetourAttach(&(PVOID &)Real_Memcpy, Mine_Memcpy);
        DetourTransactionCommit();
        break;

    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        DetourTransactionBegin();
        DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
        DetourDetach(&(PVOID &)Real_Memcpy, Mine_Memcpy);
        DetourTransactionCommit();
        break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

This is a program which I want to hook, but hooks only work in end of program, happens only once:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    char asd[20];
    cout << "copy" << endl;
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    int a = strlen("Neviem co mam");
    cout << a << endl;
    void *(*p_fun)(void *dest, const void *src, size_t count) = &memcpy;
    printf("0x%p\n",p_fun);

    memcpy(asd,"Neviem co mam",a+1);
    cout << "after" << endl;
    cout << asd << endl;
    memcpy(asd,"Neviem co mam",a+1);
    cout << "after" << endl;
    cout << asd << endl;
    memcpy(asd,"Neviem co mam",a+1);
    cout << "after" << endl;
    cout << asd << endl;

    cin.get();
    cin.get();

}
```

I want to run the hook each time, when `memcpy` is called and show goof values.

Comment: there was mistake on begining shuold be:

Comment: #include <windows.h>
#include<iostream>
#include "detours\detours.h"

Comment: Do you inject the dll fast enough? I.e. on program start?

Comment: (It is probably not the case, but `memcpy` might get optimized out -- i.e. replaced with some inline code...disabling optimization _might_ help)

Comment: Thanks man i will try it and change it